# count() returning soft deleted items in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fluent, soft-delete

I have a model `Comments` that uses soft deleting: it has a `one-to-many` relationship with my `Post` model.

My site will have a native mobile app associated with it and I need to send a count of the comments to it when I send the information about a post and for some reason it is returning the count WITH the soft deleted items.

I've got the Post array working and sending the comment count using

```
protected $appends = array('score','commentcount', 'ups', 'downs');
```

and

```
public function getCommentcountAttribute()
{    
     return DB::table('comments')
         ->where('post_id',$this->id)
         ->where('deleted_at','=',NULL)
         ->count();    
}
```

in my post model. I've also tried

```
public function getCommentcountAttribute()
{
    return $this->comments()->count();
}
```

and

```
public function getCommentcountAttribute()
{   
    return $this->comments()->whereNull('deleted_at')->count();
    // also: return $this->comments()->where('deleted_at',NULL)->count();
}
```

also when defining the relationship I've tried adding `->whereNUll('deleted_at')` to both the `->hasMany('Comment')` and the `->belongsTo('Post')` with no luck.

I've checked the database and ran the SQL I'm expecting Fluent and Eloquent to be generating which is

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE post_id=31 and deleted_at=null
```

(31 being the post I'm using to test). Nothing is working. Let me know if you guys need to see anymore specific functions as I'd rather not post my entire models.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work with `->whereRaw('deleted_at = ?',array(NULL))`. That seems pretty hacky to me though. I'd gladly accept a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Soft Deleting in your model.

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    protected $softDelete = true;

}
```

That's it.

And you don't need to include the following where clauses in your queries:

```
return DB::table('comments')
         ->where('post_id',$this->id)
         //->where('deleted_at','=',NULL) // no needed, Laravel by default will include this condition
         ->count();   


public function getCommentcountAttribute()
{   
   // remove  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
   return $this->comments()->count();
}
```

Comment: Should have included that I have already done that. Soft Deleting is working everywhere except for when I use `->toArray()` and `count()`

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
return \App\Comments::count();
```

Soft delete works only on models, not queries:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent
{
    protected $softDelete = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is an old post the following should hopefully be helpful with others if they come across this.

For laravel V5 and above.

Add `use SoftDeletes;` to your model.

If you are trying to get the count that includes soft deletes use the following:

```
Model::withTrashed()->'yourquery'
```

If you do not want soft deleted records included then you can follow the normal convection.

```
Model::select()->get();
```